# swift2: get array of keys from dictionary sorted by values

Tags: sorting, dictionary, swift2

I am trying to get an array o keys from a dictionary where the array is sorted by values. For example:

```
//dictionary contains [alpha:C],[beta:A],[gamma:B]
```

My array should return:

```
//[beta, gamma, alpha]
```

I tried:

```
let keys = Array(myDictionary.keys).sort({ (a,b) -> Bool in
        a.compare(b) == .OrderedAscending
    })
```

but this returns the order by keys:

```
//[alpha, beta, gamma]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your dictionary

```
let dict = ["alpha":"C","beta":"A","gamma":"B"]
```

You can sort the keys by value with this code

```
let keysSortedByValue = dict.sort { $0.1 < $1.1 }.map { $0.0 }

// ["beta", "gamma", "alpha"]
```

### Update

This screenshot to answer to your comment below

[image]

Comment: Although i clicked "accepted" there is something that i don't understand. This: let dict = ["alpha":"alpha","beta":"beta","gamma":"gamma"] returns first beta then alpha and the gamma. It seems your advise does not work with strings properly

Comment: @Mic: I just tested it and it is returning `["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]`. Please see the screenshot I added to my answer. Are you sure you are using __exactly__ this input? I suspect you are using some uppercase letters...

Comment: You was correct. Because of many tests there was a 0 instead of 1 and I missed. Answer is accepted. Sorry for this. In case I gona use uppercase letters is something that I have to mind?

Comment: @Mic: if you want case-insensitive `String` sorting, you could apply `lowerCaseString` to the arguments in the sorting closure, e.g. `let keysSortedByValue = dict.sort { $0.1.lowercaseString < $1.1.lowercaseString }.map { $0.0 }`.